# Can anyone recommend any basic Amplifier software for Macs?

Tags: macos, itunes, amplification

I have some speakers connected via the headphone jack and want to control the bass etc.  Currently all music is played through iTunes.

Comment: "Amplifier software" is a bit of an oxymoron. Nearly any audio software can control the volume within the dynamic range of line-level sound, but a true hardware amplifier is typically increasing the waveform voltages far beyond what can be output by your sound card. You're probably looking for EQ software rather than amplifier software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're suggesting that you want to control *just* the EQ of your music while playing in iTunes or if you want to control the EQ of the whole system.

iTunes has an equalizer you can access via Command-2 and contains several presets. If you're looking for more bass, try the Rock preset.

If you want to control EQ for the whole system you'll have to hijack the audio. I found [this post](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showpost.php?p=579391&postcount=7) that provides some steps though I have not tried them myself.

Comment: [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/) is a great solution if you want to do this for *any* application.  Among the available audio affects is a 32 channel equalizer.  But if you're using iTunes, the built in equalizer is usually just fine as @orangechicken suggests.